# How can we change height of tool window's title bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I know of an option to hide the title bar, but I want to reduce height of title bar of tool windows such as "Output" or "Properties".

Comment: Not possible, I think. Try to get use to it.

Comment: maybe there is a setting for in windows registry?

Comment: I don't think they added code for that. The height is probably hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we change height of tool window's title bar in Visual Studio?

**Actually**, there is no such option or key to control the title height of a tool window in VS IDE.

**Visual Studio** does not allow to modify the title height of a tool window in VS IDE by default. And there is no such extensions to realize what you want.

**Microsoft** does not seem to open such interface. And what you want needs to inherit the VS built-in extension interface so that it can rewrite the title height of the tool window in VS IDE.

**As a suggestion**, you can [suggest a feature on our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to reflect your requirements and I think Microsoft will consider your requirements carefully and give you a satisfactory feedback.

Hope it could help you.